How to setup routeEnhancer for EXT:news which works in redirct module for linking accross languages
While everything works fine on list, detail and category pages with routeEnhancers setup as given in the documentation  – I'm struggling to get it working on the redirects module.
Configuring the linkhandler as described here, I'm able to select a news entry as target. By using an additional param for the language (e.g. L=1) the redirect works as aspected and the user get's the selected target news entry – but only as long as there is no routeEnhancer for news.
With an active routeEnhancer the generated URL consists of both languages and looks something like this: www.domain.com/newsdetailpage-default-lang/newstitle-target-langguage.
Are there any suggestions how to solve that?
(TYPO3 v12.4 and News v11.4.1)

Without having looked any deeper, it looks as if a leading slash is missing somewhere in the path.

How did you add the additional param for the language? Configuring the linkhandler as you described there is no option to add additional params.

@Mogens, the select dialog shows a field for adding additional parameters. The generated link looks like: t3://record?identifier=tx_news&uid=123 - - - L=1

I had the additional params deactivated globally in my ckeditor :-)

You should take a look at the DatabaseRecordLinkBuilder:
vendor/typo3/cms-frontend/Classes/Typolink/DatabaseRecordLinkBuilder.php
In Line 60 and following the record is loaded and language field is analyzed. If you add forceLink = true to TypoScript of the tx_news recordLinks configuration this part is skipped and the raw record is loaded. Maybe this helps you.
config.recordLinks.tx_news {
    forceLink = true
    typolink {
        # Detail page
        parameter = 123
        additionalParams.data = field:uid
        additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]=|
    }
}

If that does not solve the problem, you could Debug the DatabaseRecordLinkBuilder and check whats going on, when the link is build.
